# When creating a new blank C# ASP.NET Empty Website nothing shows up in the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So I want to start learning ASP.NET and I got a WROX book to start learning it. I have access to get Visual Studio 2012 from my college, and I installed it. In the book it says that there should be a ton of files in the solution expert. Like default.aspx, an images folder etc. Yet when I open a new blank webpage I get just a web.config file. So I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty solution contains nothing, therefore it is called **empty**.

If you want to see a sample, you should choose ASP.NET Web Forms Application or ASP.NET MVC Application.

Comment: ...... -_- I feel like an idiot thank you, the book I am using had that one highlighted but in the text it said ASP.NET Web Form Site... Thank you for solving my problem. Haven't really used Stackoverflow so do I just arrow you for you to get credit and points.

Comment: No probs. Feel free to ask questions, because when you need to invest hours in looking for solution, somebody may help you without effort. Mark the post as answer if it's answered your question.

Comment: Ya trust me, I spent a good amount of time in this. A few installs and uninstalls as well as a completely wipe and reformatting fully.